# How might I show only the first level of an Exposed Taxonomy Filter in Views?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

In Drupal 7, I have a exposed filter set at first in its hierarchical fashion

[image]

with the following structure:

```
Adjunct
-Adjunct Lecturer
-Adjunct Professor
Chairperson
Clinician
Container
-Director Advising & Student Affairs
-Managing Director TIC
Deans
-Associate Dean Undergraduate Advising Administration
Department Chair
Emeritus
-Associate Professor Emeritus
-Professor Emeritus
Lecturer
-Senior Lecturer
Professor
-Assistant Professor
-Assistant Professor in Residence
-Associate Professor
-Associate Professor in Residence
-Research Scientist & Professor
Speech Pathologist
Visiting
-Visiting Assistant Professor
-Visiting Associate Professor
```

In the exposed filter, is there a way to expose only the parent (first level) items (Adjunct, Deans, Department Chair, etc)?

Update: Grouping the exposed filter in views did not work ([ticket](https://drupal.org/node/1810148)).

Comment: have you tried adding " Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth)" and set the depth to "1".

Comment: Hi Bala: I'd suggest moving this down to the answer section below. I've not yet tried but that sounds like something to test today. Thank you.

Comment: Bala: That filter works nicely. First, please put it in the answers! :) Second question is how to only expose parent level taxonomy in the drop down menu?

Comment: I updated my answer and for the second you asked the another question, so I answered there.

Comment: @Richard, I think this duplicate to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94246/trying-to-remove-options-form-an-exposed-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add " Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth)" and set the depth to "1" it will show the first level of terms.

For Drupal 6:

[Views Taxonomy: limit exposed dropdown by term depth](https://drupal.org/project/tax_depth_lim_filter) module provides enhanced functionality for the exposed dropdown filter for taxonomy terms in Views.

> Exposed term filters can already be limited to display only terms
>   selected in the Views interface. But what if content creators add new
>   taxonomy terms? They will have to navigate the Views interface and add
>   these new terms to the list of terms shown by exposed filters.

Comment: An otherwise excellent answer and worthy of an upvote (which I did). But, I'm using D7. I've just edited my question to jot down that information.

Comment: @Richard did you find answer for D7?